# Occasional incomplete uploads for large files with HttpPut and Apache PHP in Android

Tags: php, android, http

I have written Android code to upload a large file (10MB+) via HTTP Put to an Apache PHP server (I cannot use FTP because my application sometimes operates on mobile networks, and I hear many mobile carriers do not allow FTP-If I am wrong, please correct me). The function that handles the actual upload is called by an AsyncTask, so it does not cause the application to hang. However, I have some concerns about the method of uploading-sometimes I get incomplete uploads, sometimes with "false positives"-I get a signal back that the file uploaded, only to check and see nothing.

My background is deeper in C than Java and I'm not entirely clear about Java's automatic memory management, so if my questions seem somewhat ridiculous, forgive me.

**So, here are my questions:**

1) Might the upload problems be caused by memory issues? The code was originally written to read everything at once by the original developer, but I have re-written it below to use a ByteArrayOutputStream and read the file chunk by chunk. I still worry that the InputStream is trying to read everything at once on initialization. Am I just misunderstanding InputStream, or does it behave more like a File pointer in C?

2) I dislike calling new everytime in the while loop-I suspect that, like in C, new memory is being allocated all the time, but I am not sure if calling null before re-initialization really helps here. Is this causing a leak here? I only ask because I presume that Java's Memory Management somehow ensures not to allow more memory to the heap and keeps track of references.

3) The uploading stops if the phone goes into standby. Is there anyway to keep the upload moving when this happens?

4) Might the PHP server code be missing something in terms of reporting networking errors/issues? I have included as much as I can for handling write errors, but I feel somehow this could be written better.

*Also, I am not constrained to using HttpPut-this was simply a method suggested to me. I am open to changing things on the server side to support a better method of file transfer.*

**Android Java code (function in upload client):**

```
private boolean transmitBytes(Uri uri) 
{
        /**/
        ByteArrayEntity requestEntity;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        float temp = 0.0f;
        float temp1 = 0.0f;
        long total = 0;
        int buffSize = 102400;
        byte[] buffer;
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (length <= 1048576) {
                buffer = new byte[buffSize];
            } else {
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            }
            // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
            int len = 0;

            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Upload", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String userid = sharedPreferences.getString("userid", ""); // Set the first segment with
                                                                       // the resume flag at 0 so
                                                                       // wipes anything of that
                                                                       // filename on
            // srvr.
            String putURL = Constants.UPLOAD_MEDIA_URL;
            putURL += "mediatype=";
            putURL += mediatype;
            putURL += "&file_name=";
            putURL += new File(vidFileName).getName();
            putURL += "&usrname=";
            putURL += userid;
            putURL += "&filesize=";
            putURL += Long.toString(length);
            putURL += "&sha256sum=";
            putURL += cksum;
            putURL += "&resume=0";
            putURL = putURL.replace(" ", "");
            // Read the first segment for transmission.

            if ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);

                // Dump first segment into requestEntity
                requestEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(byteBuffer.toByteArray());

                // Wipe byte buffer after you are done writing with it to clear out contents.
                byteBuffer.reset();

                // Transmit segment.
                HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(putURL);

                httpPut.setEntity(requestEntity);

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

              //Set timeouts. If no response by timeout, mark failure.
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

                // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used and we go to infinite.
                //Set to 3000 ms here.
                   int timeoutConnection = 5000;
                   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

                // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data. If not set, will be infinite.
                   int timeoutSocket = 5000;
                   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

                httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);

                // Transmit via PUT
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                entity.getContent();

                // Set resume tag to 1.
                putURL = putURL.replaceAll("&resume=0", "&resume=1");
            }
            // write the remaining segments, (bufferSize) at a time
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);

                requestEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(byteBuffer.toByteArray());

                // Wipe byte buffer after you are done writing with it to clear out contents.
                byteBuffer.reset();

                HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(putURL);

                httpPut.setEntity(requestEntity);


                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                //Set timeouts. If no response by timeout, mark failure.
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

                // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. Set to 3000 ms here.
                   int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

                // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                   int timeoutSocket = 5000;
                   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

                httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);

                // Transmit via PUT
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                String result = convertStreamToString(is);

        //9/10/2013: TODO-check for response codes in addition to these. Maybe, there is an error code being returned?
                if (result.contains("0") || result.contains("1")) {
                    total += len;

                    temp = total * 100;
                    temp1 = temp / length;

                    //Updates object within async task.
                    mProgressDialog.setProgress((int) temp1);
                }

                else
                {
                    /* Because this is controlled by an AsyncTask, we must bubble up that
                     * there has been a failure in the system if the user is unable to upload. 
                     * 
                     */
                     return false;
                }/**/



            }
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 


        catch (ConnectTimeoutException e ){
              //Took too long to connect to remote host
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
            }

            //Handled already by IOException.
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
              //Remote host didn’t respond in time
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }/**/

        //In case anything else is missing...
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != inputStream)
                    inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**PHP Server Side code:**

```
<?php

      $CHUNK = 8192;
      //$header_size=1024;

      //7/16/2012: this will now be set to 0 by default, and only to 1 upon complete transmission of file.
      $rslt=0;
      $bytes_written=0;


    //set error handler
    set_error_handler("errorLogFunction");

      try {

          //Error handler test
          //echo($test);

          if (!($putData = fopen("php://input", "r")))
          {
            //throw new Exception ("Can't get PUT data.");
            $log = new KLogger ( "putfile_php_log.txt" , KLogger::DEBUG );

            // Do database work that throws an exception
            $log->LogError("Can't get PUT data.");

            // Print out some information
            $log->LogInfo($errMsg);
          }

          else
          {

            $filedata_arr=explode("&",$filedata);

            $mediadata_tmp=explode("=",$filedata_arr[0]);

            $filetype=$mediadata_tmp[1];

            $filename_tmp=explode("=",$filedata_arr[1]);

            $filename=$filename_tmp[1];

            $username_tmp=explode("=",$filedata_arr[2]);

            $usr=$username_tmp[1];

            $filesize_tmp=explode("=",$filedata_arr[3]);

            $filesize=(int)$filesize_tmp[1];

            $sha256sum_tmp=explode("=",$filedata_arr[4]);

            $sha256sum=$sha256sum_tmp[1];

            //echo "SHA read: " . $sha256sum . "<BR>";

            $resume_tmp=explode("=",$filedata_arr[5]);

            $resume=$resume_tmp[1];

              //6/18/2013: Replace any spaces with underscores. For now, don't add date to filename.

              $tmp2=ereg_replace(" ","_",$filename);

              $targetFilename=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/received/'.$filetype.'/'.$usr."_".$tmp2;

              //7/27/2012: Check if the user exists-if the user does not exist, do not allow the upload. Do this only once-if the file exists, don't run this check.
              if (!file_exists($targetFilename))
              {
                  if (checkIfUsernameExists($usr)==0)
                  {
                      $rslt=-9;
                  }
              }

            //Continue on only if file could be written
            if ($rslt>=0)
            {
                // Open the file for writing
                if ($resume==0)
                {
                    if (!($fp = fopen($targetFilename, "w")))
                      {
                          //throw new Exception ("Can't write to tmp file");
                          //echo json_encode(-1);
                          //throw new Exception ("Can't get PUT data.");
                            $log = new KLogger ( "putfile_php_log.txt" , KLogger::DEBUG );

                            // Do database work that throws an exception
                            $log->LogError("Can't write to tmp file.");

                            // Print out some information
                            $log->LogInfo($errMsg);
                          $rslt=-1;
                      }
                }

                else
                {
                      if (!($fp = fopen($targetFilename, "a")))
                      {
                          //throw new Exception ("Can't write to tmp file");
                          //throw new Exception ("Can't get PUT data.");
                            $log = new KLogger ( "putfile_php_log.txt" , KLogger::DEBUG );

                            // Do database work that throws an exception
                            $log->LogError("Can't append to tmp file.");

                            // Print out some information
                            $log->LogInfo($errMsg);

                          //echo json_encode(-2);
                          $rslt=-2;
                      }

                      else
                      {
                        $bytes_written=filesize($targetFilename);
                      }
                }

                if ($rslt>=0)
                {
                    // Read the data a chunk at a time and write to the file.
                    while ($data = fread($putData, $CHUNK)) 
                    {
                      $chunk_read = strlen($data);
                      if (($block_write = fwrite($fp, $data)) != $chunk_read)
                        {
                            //throw new Exception ("Can't write more to tmp file");

                            //throw new Exception ("Can't get PUT data.");
                            $log = new KLogger ( "putfile_php_log.txt" , KLogger::DEBUG );

                            // Do database work that throws an exception
                            $log->LogError("Can't write more to tmp file.");

                            // Print out some information
                            $log->LogInfo($errMsg);
                            //echo json_encode(-3);
                            $rslt=-3;
                            break;
                        }

                      $bytes_written += $block_write;

                      //7/2/2012: Commented out temporarily until resume upload feature supported.
                      //echo "<BR>" . $tot_write . " written.";
                      //echo $tot_write;
                    }

                    if ( ! fclose($fp) )
                    {
                      //throw new Exception ("Can't close tmp file");
                      //echo json_encode(-4);

                      //throw new Exception ("Can't get PUT data.");
                        $log = new KLogger ( "putfile_php_log.txt" , KLogger::DEBUG );

                        // Do database work that throws an exception
                        $log->LogError("Can't close tmp file.");

                        // Print out some information
                        $log->LogInfo($errMsg);

                      $rslt=-4;
                    }

                    unset($putData);

                     // now the params can be used like any other variable
                    // see below after input has finished

                        // Check file length and SHA-256

                        //6/16/2012: no need to do filesize check anymore. Just do checksum.
                        /*if ($tot_write != $file_size)
                        {
                          throw new Exception ("Wrong file size");
                          //echo json_encode(-6);
                          $rslt=-6;
                        }*/

                        if (($rslt>=0) && ($bytes_written==$filesize))
                        {

                            //7/27/2012: Skipping checksum check because of iOS. Will consider adding another flag for checksum later.
                            /*$sha256_arr = explode(' ',exec("sha256sum $targetFilename"));
                            $sha256 = $sha256_arr[0];

                            if ($sha256 != $sha256sum) 
                            {
                              //throw new Exception ("Wrong sha256");
                              //echo json_encode(-7);
                              $rslt=-7;
                            }

                            //if the checksums and filesizes match, return success.
                            else
                            {
                                $rslt=1;
                            }*/

                            //echo "<BR>Calculated SHA-256: " . $sha256 . "<BR>";
                            //echo "Read in SHA-256: " . $sha256sum . "<BR>";

                            $rslt=1;
                        }

                        //If the filesize and checksum match, send the messages indicating success.
                }




                }

            }//if (put data)

          }//try

        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            //var_dump($e->getMessage());
            //echo json_encode(-5);
            $rslt=-5;
        }






        echo json_encode($rslt);
?>
```